# Handlerbars.js using an helper function in a #if statement

Tags: javascript, templating, mustache

With [handlebars.js](http://www.handlebarsjs.com/) I want to display two blocks of html depending of a resulting json.

Let's say I want to thanks my user for ordering items at my shop.
I write my handlerbars.js template like this :

```
<p>{{name}}</p>
{{#if costIsZero}}
  Can't find any order
{{else}}
    You bought {{cost}} items in our shop, thanks.
{{/if}}
```

I'm coding a simple helper for costIsZero like this :

```
Handlebars.registerHelper('costIsZero', function(){
    return this.cost == 0
});
```

When I mix it with the following json data :

```
var data = {
  "name":"foo",
  "cost": 9
};
```

Whatever the value of "cost" is the {{#if costIsZero}} seems always to be true.
If I comment out the helper itself, thus having nothing for costIsZero it returns always false.

All the code above is available as a JSFiddle there http://jsfiddle.net/gsSyt/

What I'm doing wrong ?

Maybe I'm hijacking the way handlebars.js work, but in that case, How should I implement my feature with handlebars.js ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Helpers are not invoked when evaluating an expression such as `costIsZero`.

You could create a custom helper that works as an alternative to `if`:

```js
Handlebars.registerHelper('ifCostIsZero', function(block) {
    if (this.cost == 0) {
        return block(this);
    } else {
        return block.inverse(this);
    }
});
```

Which you would use like this:

```html
{{#ifCostIsZero}}
    Can't find any order
{{else}}
    You bought {{cost}} items in our shop, thanks.
{{/ifCostIsZero}}
```

Alternatively, you can use the stock `if` (or `unless`) since your test is against zero :

```html
{{#if cost}}
    You bought {{cost}} items in our shop, thanks.
{{else}}
    Can't find any order
{{/if}}
```

You can play with both options at http://jsfiddle.net/gsSyt/41/

Comment: Just a small comment. block(this) is no longer valid. You have to use block.fn(this);

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Handlebars.registerHelper('if', function(conditional, block) {
  if(this.cost == 0) {
    return block(this);
  } else {
    return block.inverse(this);
  }
})
```

http://jsfiddle.net/mZbtk/2/